# How to delete this pattern with sed or awk?

Tags: awk, sed

```
#======================================================================
#NAME
#======================================================================
gen (
         id  111
         descr  Test 1
         txcd  
                content           
)
#======================================================================
#NAME
#======================================================================
gen (
         id  112
         descr  Test 2
         txcd
                content
)
#======================================================================
#NAME
#======================================================================
gen (
         id  123
         descr  Test 3
         txcd
                content
)
```

I have this pattern, and have tried to find a way to delete a certain id using sed or awk.
I pass the ID using a function parameter, $1. I've looked it up on stack but couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

`sed -i "/gen \(/{:a;N;/\)/!ba};/$1/d" file`

At a certain point when editing this sed command it did delete a line, but just the line where the ID itself was.

This is the one I've been working with, I've made small changes but nothing worked thus far. I'm supposed to delete the hashtags on top as well, but to begin with, I was mainly trying to delete the gen pattern.

Comment: You were nearly there. When you quoted ( placed a `\ ` before a character) the `(` and `)` you changed their meaning into a group instead of a literal `(` or `)`. Perhaps a function `f () { sed -i '/^gen (/{:a;N;/^)/M!ba;/'"$1"'/d' "${2:-file}"; }` would meet your requirements (if you use bash)?

Comment: It is bash. I was getting an error and the parentheses were being indicated as the reason, so I thought I might have to escape them.

Comment: It is safer to surround sed commands by single quotes (as in my first comment) and then the side effects of bash interpolation will not occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a lone `)` always terminates one record, this is easy enough in Awk.

```sh
awk -v RS=')' -v ORS=')' '!/id +112/' file
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did notice that I could do something with the closing parentheses, but I'm really inexperienced with sed, and even more inexperienced with awk. But I'm definitely noticing that it's more than worthwhile to really learn it. Thanks again.

Comment: Tested on a Mac, which platform are you on?

Comment: I'm using red hat linux

Comment: Actually just noticed it leaves a parentehese

Comment: *at the end of the file with the edited solution, no matter where I delete, middle beginning or end, extra parenthesis at the end.

Comment: That's what "terminates a record" means. Maybe ask a new question with realistic input if you still need help?

Comment: I know it terminates each record, but there shouldn't be two closing parentheses at the end of a record, but since it's always outputted in the last line no matter what record I delete I just delete the last line. So it's solved. Thanks, had no clue what ORS ans RS were but looked it up, really useful